# Database design for a shop issue: storing changeable price

Tags: sql, database, database-design, structure

I am new to database design.

I have an assignment to design a relational database for a company that has 3 shops that fulfills these requirements:

1) A product has an ID, quantity, price and new product can be added.

2) Each shop has a name, and an ID

3) Do NOT create tables that store products of each shop, but only a "History" table that has a "status" attribute that keeps track of transaction history only (IN: add new product, OUT: check out product). Each transaction has a productID, "status", quantity check (in/out), history (timestamp), shopID. Manager only needs to make query to see each shop's current stocks of the products. Datasets should be like this:

[image: Transaction Table]

(barcode is just replaced with productID)

4) Price: design a table structure for the price such that:

a) Price can be changed. When a price changes, there should be a method to keep track with the history and the old value of the price changes. Manager can make query to see when the price was changed and how much the old price was.

b) Discount: a discount of a particular product in a particular shop can have a discount value. For example in that week the new shop is open, its product A has a discount B% during that week.

c) Manager should be able to make a query to retrieve data of the total revenue.

I was given the first 3 tasks to design last week, and this week the fourth requirement came up and I need to change the design accordingly. How can I change my design to cope with the last requirement? Thank you.

My current design for the first 3 requirements: [image: Database]

Comment: Remove `price` from `product`. Create a new table with an FK to `product` a `price` and a time stamp column to indicate when the price was changed to the price given in that row. Then you have modeled the price history of a product. For discount create a new table with FKs to product and shop. Also include the time stamp since when the discount is given and the amount of it.

Comment: I did that. But I still haven't figured out how to calculate the total revenue. Do I need to also store the actual price (price*discount) in the Transaction table so that I can calculate the revenue after?

Comment: Are there different prices in different stores (the base price, without accounting for the discount)?

Comment: No, just assume each product has only one price regardless of shops. Only discount value can be different.